# ASPX + Vb.Vet simple in-browser calculation form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am absolutely certain I'm mixing two kinds of syntax incorrectly due to trying to hack together from different samples. I am not familiar with either ASPX nor VB.Net, and am stuck at the first hurdle.

The aim is for a user to enter a string of numbers (from a lastlogontimestamp in epoch time) and return it formatted as a local date/time.

It's failing at line 4 in IIS 7 - `CS1026: ) expected`.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<script runat="server">
Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    long value = (long)txt1.text
    DateTime pwdLastSet = (DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(value)).ToLocalTime
    lbl1.Text="Converted date: " & pwdLastSet
End Sub
</script>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
Enter the date string:
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
<p><asp:Label id="lbl1" runat="server" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**
Thanks for the comments, everyone. I'm definitely not a programmer. I did use the C# solution suggested in the comments as an exercise, with slight corrections. However, I am slightly more familiar with VB, so I should stick with that - the accepted answer was more intuitive to me.

```
<script runat="server">
void submit(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    long value = Convert.ToInt64(txt1.Text);
    DateTime conValue = (DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(value)).ToLocalTime();
    lbl1.Text = "Converted date: " + conValue;
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's VB not C#, not really an expert on webForms but maybe you should change the language on the first line to VB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Page level language is defined as C#    , so the compiler will try to compile the code as C#, and hence the expected exception is appearing. So changing the Language solves the exception

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" %>
```

Now the actual Vb code is also wrong. As the way **[variables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET/Variables)** and **[casting](http://www.codemag.com/Article/0301111)** is written its not the Way happen in VB.

```
 <script runat="server" >
    Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Dim value = txt1.Text
            Dim pwdLastSet = (DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(value)).ToLocalTime
        lbl1.Text="Converted date: " & pwdLastSet
    End Sub
    </script>
```

So I will suggest get the hold of language which you want to proceed with C# or VB, and do the changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out you have posted a weird hybrid between VB and C#. I'm not very familiar with C# but this should be more like it.

```
void submit(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    long value = (long)txt1.text;
    DateTime pwdLastSet = (DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(value)).ToLocalTime();
    lbl1.Text = "Converted date: " + pwdLastSet;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to convert the `string` to a `long`, but this got me on the right track.